# How to download a file from URL in android using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, download

I want to download a file from URL.Like if i click on download button the file url should get connect and it should get downloaded into phone memory or SDCard of android.

Can anyone please help me how to get this to work using phonegap?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the [FileTransfer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) API from Phonegap or CoreDova. Here is the sample code from the same source:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://some.server.com/download.php");

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    filePath,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    }
);
```

To save the file on SDCard use [FileWriter](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter)

```
function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
        console.log("contents of file now 'some sample text'");
        writer.truncate(11);  
        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
            console.log("contents of file now 'some sample'");
            writer.seek(4);
            writer.write(" different text");
            writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
                console.log("contents of file now 'some different text'");
            }
        };
    };
    writer.write("some sample text");
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

Comment: Also, please save the files in FileSystemRoot/data/your.company.app folder. This will avoid clutter on the SD card.